# Analog sticks not working, qtsixa+PCSX combination

Tags: drivers, usb, configuration

A few days ago I finally got my PS3 controller to work with QtSixA, and then in PCSX after some tweaking with the controls.

But, I haven't figured out how on earth I will be able to get the analog sticks working. I've been triyng to add them in the controls for all angles in PCSX, where you move the analog stick the way it's supposed to be and then clicking a button to change the setting.

I've enabled joysticks in the options for the controller, and my options in my controller 
are:

- [x] Enable buttons
- [x] Enable sensitive buttons
- [x] Enable Axis
- [ ] Enable accellerometers
- [ ] Enable Acceleration
- [ ] Enable Speed
- [ ] Enable position

The controller is a standard PS3 controller, Dualshock 3. Plugged in with USB cable.
Thanks in forehand!

Answer (score 2):

some older games doesn't support the analog stick on Playstation One
Therefore was the Analog Button on original PSX1 Controllers

But you can have a workaround for this

Configure the Device to act as mouse/keyboard input in qtsixa using 2H4U profile is great)
disable joystick input

in this config the analog stick is keyboard up/left/down/right

start PCSX go to Configure PAD set it to none
set DPAD directions to the analog stick settings

quit PCSX

go to qtsixa, enable joystick AND mouse/keyboard

open PCSX
configure PAD set it to Playstation Controller

NOW the analog stick sends also the keyboard controls to the DPAD config
by that config you are able to control any non analog PSX Game by the analog stick

TRICKY, isn't it